# How to handle connecting to a database only used by the service layer / business logic?

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, google-cloud-firestore

In order to understand the following question you need to know that I'm a complete novice in the whole Spring Boot ecosystem, as well as, the architectural philosophy behind it.

### Task

The app I'm developing with Spring Boot requires, on a business level, some data which are simple collections stored in Firestore. Now, the user when inputting some parameters on the front end (the REQUEST method) and asking for the execution of a certain algorithm on the back-end will trigger the following:
 **1.** The business logic part of the app is going to retrieve some data from the database based on the user input.
 **2.** It's going to process this data and create a RESPONSE based on the retrieved data and a number of other user input.

### The problem

**So, I'm not really sure if I should be even bothering with creating a service connection for the database since the only one accessing it will be the business logic layer.** The database will primarily be build for reads only while at the same time I want to leave open the possibility of later creating a system for auto-updating it (again, only from the back-end, no user interaction/input). Also, what I'm possibly forgetting is the support for multiple connections. Each user may trigger the main algorithm to run utilizing a different set of data retrieved from the database. In that vein, while I would love to leverage the capabilities of Firestore, is the use of it justified in the sense of the data being static for the time being?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should strive to keep the business logic as pure as possible from implementation choices. Ideally your business logic should not talk to network, file systems or databases. It should be just the pure, refined business logic.
You will then have outer layers that abstract as much as possible these external dependencies. In the case of database, usually you'd have a persistence layer of sorts, which is responsible for accessing directly the database.
For instance, lets say the business logic needs a list of clients sorted by last name. From the business perspective, they're calling a method fetchClientsSortedByLastName() and what that method does is a black box. If at a later moment you decide to switch from Firestore to Postgres or Mysql, you only need to change the persistence method. The business logic will remain exactly the same.